# ASP app runs locally but not when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis

I have an ASP.net application (.net 4.5) which runs fine when running via Visual Studio (2013), but when I go to deploy it (even to a standalone IIS application pool locally) it fails with a `StackOverflowException` in `mscorlib.dll`.

The stack trace (when a debugging option appears) is only:

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I'm using Sharepoint `ClientContext` with fairly intensive processing. Could this simply be a memory issue?

My computer has 8GB memory so have tried increasing the IIS's Output Cache to `262144000` (bytes) to no avail.

Can anyone else think of any reason why an application would run fine when launched with Visual Studio but not when deployed?

Windows 8
Visual Studio 2013 
IIS 8.5

EDIT: Event log output

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1055.0, time stamp: 0x563c12de
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000001b748
Faulting process ID: 0x1a94
Faulting application start time: 0x01d16353b00ade26
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report ID: f23d7e87-cf46-11e5-82a4-000c295a1d22
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

UPDATE:

After attaching the debugger to `w3wp` process (thanks @Jamie Pollard) I was able to find recursion happening in some unmanaged code. Again, why this wouldn't show when running locally I'm not sure!

Comment: StackOverflowException is definitely a memory issue. But you have to get its call stack, either from event log or s crash dump, so as to get closer to its cause.

Comment: Try deploying a Debug version of your program and see if you get better error info/stack trace  (you may not as exception reporting for things like StackOverflows can be a particular challenge in many environments)

Comment: Thanks guys, but nothing more came up after deploying a debug version, and the event log as not very helpful either (see edited answer)

Comment: Attach visual studios debugger to the w3wp process, then load your page, you should be able to get a call stack from there

Comment: "*Can anyone else think of any reason why an application would run fine when launched with VS but not when deployed?*"  Unfortunately, there is an immense number of possible causes and just "StackOverflow" doesn't tell you much.  The one thing that it does tell you is that something was using your stack pretty hard and there's usually only one class of errors that does that: infinite recursion.  Runaway recursion is mostly too generic and code-dependent for us to guess at, except for one possibility: infinite *exception-reporting* recursion. IE, an error trying to report another error.

Comment: Just to make sure... you have Global.asax available for error handling and don't depend on some in-code magic? Another thing: remember that the stack is not your memory. You can have 8gb of memory and still only 1mb of stack size. Also, increasing the memory/cache/whatever has absolutely no influence on the stack size.

Comment: If you can afford deploying your project with /unsafe option enabled, I found something nice: [`BOOL WINAPI SetThreadStackGuarantee(_Inout_ PULONG StackSizeInBytes)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which sets the input value to the stacksize, if input is a pointer to a zero value. You can basically use it to log your stacksize in any windows environment prior to running into an overflow :)

Comment: I found 2 references that might be of help, first mscorlib.dll errors are often caused if there is a problem with the framework install and you may have to uninstall and reinstall .NET framework 4.5. Second, The issue occurs because an object that is being referenced is dereferenced by the garbage collector in common language runtime 4 (CLR4).
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_programs/fatal-error-mscorlibdll/daa29708-e66b-4cba-a37a-fa9fee39d116
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2640103